# Error in submodule connection in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I have two submodules in compound module. I try to connect them using gate, but it creates this error:

> Error in module(cmodule) wnetwork.host0 during network setup.
>   Gate 'wnetwork.host[0].gate$i[0]' is not connected to a submodule(or
>   internally to another gate of the same module)

My compound module code is

**wirelessnode.ned:**

```
package core;

import org.mixim.modules.power.battery.BatteryStats;
import org.mixim.modules.power.battery.SimpleBattery;

module wirelessnode
{       
   parameters:
    volatile double Energy @unit(mW) = default(10.0mW);    
    double Tx_energy @unit(mW) = default(0.8mW);
    double Tx_interval @unit(s) = default(0.5s);
    @display("bgb=210,450,white;i=device/palm;i2=status/battery;b=40,40,rect");
submodules:
    batteryStats: BatteryStats {
        @display("p=110,221;i=block/table,#FF8040");       
    }
    battery: SimpleBattery {
        @display("p=101,90;i=block/plug,#FF8000");
                            }
 }
```

**wirelessnodehost.ned:**

```
package core;

module wirelessnodehost extends wirelessnode
{
    gates:
        inout gate[];
}
```

**wnetwork.ned:**

```
package core;

import core.wirelessnodehost;

network wnetwork
{
    parameters:
        int numDevices=default(3);
      submodules:
        host[numDevices]: wirelessnodehost;

    connections:
             for i = 0..numDevices-2 {
host[i].gate++ <--> host[i+1].gate++;
 }

}
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the error message, it says: `wnetwork.host[0].gate$i[0]` is not connected to a *submodule* (or internally to another gate of the same module). (see emphasis), so the problem is NOT that connecting the two module is wrong somehow, but instead the internals of the `wirelessnodehost` are incorrect.

Specifically, you are defining the `wirelessnodehost` as a compound module (a module built up from other modules by connecting them together, while you do not specify any submodules in it). I assume that you have some C++ code for the `wirelessnodehost`. In this case you must define it as `simple wirelessnodehost`. Only simple modules have a corresponding code and they are allowed to process the incoming messages using their code. On the other hand compound modules should always pass the incoming message to a submodule for processing, that's why the runtime complaining. You have not connected the gate internally so the runtime does not know where to pass the incoming message.

As a side note, the fact that you extend `wirelessnode` module (which itself should have a corresponding C++ code and should be defined as 'simple') is rather suspicious. If the code that handles the behavior of the node is implemented in the `wirelessnode` class, then it does not know anything about the gate that is defined in the `wirelessnodehost`. I would suggest to take a deeper look at the part of the [OMNeT++ manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec123) which describes the differences between simple and compound modules.

Comment: ok , fine . so how could i use the submodules properties associated with my simple module? for an example i make the wirelessnode as simple module and further i create a compound module as wirelessnodebattery. so, how could i use the battery power of individual node of the wirelessnode ?

Comment: You are asking a different and rather general question in a comment. You should decide whether the actual answer answers your *original* question. If yes, you should accept it. If you have further questions, you should again specify it and create an other question that again includes the code that causing issues.